# Store Auth0 user info into Angular2+ service

Tags: angular, auth0

I am currently migrating an existing Angular2+ code using Auth0 authentication.
I have to give up the Lock widget to use the universal login.

Here is a sample of my new service using Auth0.js :

```
  public infosUtilisateur: any = undefined;

  public RafraichirInfosUtilisateur()
  {
    let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    if(accessToken && !this.infosUtilisateur)
    {
      this.webAuth.client.userInfo(accessToken, function(err, user) 
      {
        this.infosUtilisateur = user; // Here goes the pain
      });
    }
  }
```

Whenever my function is called, i get this error :

```
Cannot set property 'infosUtilisateur' of undefined
```

I do not understand why i can't access to my service property inside the API call.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `callback function` without `function` keyword and use the `=>` insead. This preserves the calling context.

```
if(accessToken && !this.infosUtilisateur)
{
  this.webAuth.client.userInfo(accessToken, (err, user) =>  
  {
    this.infosUtilisateur = user; // Here goes the pain
  });
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that those 2 syntaxes have different behaviours, works like a charm thank you ! :)